# Does SELECT in Django comes with onchange event?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

User goes to a page which has a SELECT choice list. Once he picks a choice, without submit button, but rather by SELECTION, we render a new page which is process by a different view (in a different app).

```
CHOICES = {('EDIT','EDIT'), ('ASSIGN', 'ASSIGN'), # etc # }
select = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICES))
```

Now, I am pretty clueless how to go about writing my view.

**choice_view.py** renders **choice.html**;   then choosing *EDIT* process by **edit.py** with some parameters.

http://localhost/url_1/   then (after selecting edit goes to) http://localhost/url_2/

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

Firstly, define a URL for `http://localhost/url_2/` with its `name`, `parameters` and `view` which it would run. Here, the view lies in the file **edit.py**.

Then, in the template of `http://localhost/url_1/`, i.e., **choice.html**, write a JQuery code defining the onChange function for the select field. In the onChange function, call the URL of `http://localhost/url_2/` by its name and passing the select field value as parameter to it. You can use `window.location.href` for calling the URL. This would redirect you to `http://localhost/url_2/`.

In the view inside **edit.py**, you can write the code of the process further.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Are you suggesting the url should be in the form of something like named group (which then the views willt take request, name1, name2, etc

Comment: Yes, you have to define that way. :)